# R dplyr: replace Inf values by 0?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder **how to replace the `Inf` values by 0 across all columns in the dataframe?** I have tried several examples, but most answers work only for the vectors, not for the whole dataframe, eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990961/replace-inf-nan-and-na-values-with-zero-in-a-dataset-in-r) or [replace NA but not Inf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517414/how-to-replace-all-values-using-dplyrs-across-function). I am sure there has to be some more ellegant way directly in `dplyr`!

Dummy example:

```
df <- data.frame(vals <- c(1, Inf, NA, NaN))
```

Not working conversions:

```
df[!is.finite(df)] <- 0

df %>% mutate(across(everything(), !is.finite(), -99))
```

Errors:

```
Error in is.finite(df) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

or

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 =
  across(everything(), !is.finite(), -99)`.
Caused by error in `is.finite()`:
! 0 arguments passed to 'is.finite' which requires 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[as.matrix(df) == Inf]  <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(data.frame,lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x),0)))
```

From this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188551/16730940